# If I upgrade BIRT should I upgrade existing reports or leave them as the old version?

Tags: apache, upgrade, birt

I have under 100 reports that were created and are running with BIRT 4.2.1.  Clients are accessing them via Apache Tomcat 7.0.  I have a developement clone of my production/testing enviorement, where I have BIRT 4.3.1.  If I use the existing Apache link connection to run new 4.3.1 reports I will need to upgrade the Apache "runtime" files.

What are the advantage and disadvanges of converting the existing reports to 4.3.1?

Comment: FYI - upgrade has not been going well, not sure why. http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31379-how-do-i-get-my-new-birt-431-to-use-the-use-the-same-project-and-workspace-for-everything-i-built-in-421/#entry123384

Comment: Was the upgrade successful? I am also facing the same issue. I am trying to upgrade the BIRT from 2.6.2 to 4.5.0 and I am getting AssertionError when generating reports. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442524/eclipse-birt-runtime-4-5-0-throws-assertion-error"

Comment: Upgrade not completed. Other tasks took priority, currently the application  creating data in the database is being replaced. It is unlikely a direct update will be completed on this project.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem of upgrading old version to new version but what i done is just copy the version (or) **XML TAGS** where thes **BIRT** version declared from the new version to the old one and if the any exception raise and i just fix according to that,but i didnt have that much of exception and now its working fine for me.
**NOTE:** Please be sure yourself while changing what i mentioned above
Particularly i don't know the advantages and disadvantges of upgrading but in **BIRT COMMUNITY CENTER** they have mentioned the list of new feature regarding the **4.3** version [Link](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/blog/14/entry-494-a-look-at-the-new-features-in-birt-43/)
If you came to know about anything regarding the conversion just **SHARE**